# ESLint only allow specified named imports for module

Tags: eslint

Is there a rule in ESLint that only allows you to import specified named imports from module? Let's say I have the following import statement:

```
import { Airline, Airport } from '@prisma/client';
```

And I want only allow to import specific name from that module:

```
import { Prisma, PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
```

I found the [no-restricted-imports](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-imports) but it seems to only have **allow all except** definition pattern and I need **disallow all except**.